# Finding how many numbers in a given set contain a given binary pattern

Tags: combinatorics

I came across a weird question recently in a competition, and now that the competition is complete I'm wondering how to solve similar problems (the actual competition was non-calculator and had values in place of $n_{10}$ and $k_{10}$.

Given $S = \{x_{10} | x_{10} \in \mathbb{N},  n_{10} < x_{10} < k_{10}\}$, I want to find how many $y_{10}$ exist such that $y_{10} \in S$ and $y_2$ contains the string "101"

I had no idea where to even begin this problem, so I brute-forced the solution.

What is the "proper" approach that won't take up ten minutes?

Comment: Are the numbers written in binary or decimal?

Comment: @saulspatz all $x$ are base 10 and all $y$ must have 101 in binary.

Comment: Were the original $k,n$ powers of $2$ or anything like that?

Comment: @lulu $k$ and $n$ were both in base 10 as well. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Sure, but were they powers of $2$?  I expect the problem is a lot easier if the limits are powers of $2$ since in that case you are essentially looking for binary strings of a fixed length that contain the given sequence.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I misread your question, $n$ and $k$ were not powers of two, they were 100 and 199.

Comment: Ok, though in that case the strings are quite short (at most length $8$).  Maybe brute force really is the way to go.

Comment: I agree, brute force is definitely the way to go for that range. Although if those numbers are increased significantly, I'm not sure it'd be feasible.

Comment: Why do you use the $10$ subscript, and say that "$x$ are base 10" ? That seems totally irrelevant, I don't see any property in the problem related to the decimal expansion of the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A practical method for tests**

I had a go at solving your problem by recurrence relations in 'test conditions'. This did work but I found it much easier to write out the solution by splitting up the interval into simple chunks. So for your example the working would be as follows

$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&1&1&1 \\1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\end{vmatrix}  1 \text { number}$

$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\\end{vmatrix}  2^5 \text { numbers} $

$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&1&1&1&1&1 \\1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\end{vmatrix}  3\times4-1 $

Then we can ignore the two most significant bits

$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1 \\1&1&0&0&0&0\\\end{vmatrix}   3\times4-1-4$

$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&1&1&1&1 \\1&0&1&0&0&0\\\end{vmatrix}   2^3 \text{ numbers}$

$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&1&1&1 \\1&0&0&1&0&0\\\end{vmatrix}   1 \text { number}$

Total=$60$.

This example is 'general' in the sense that it shows how one can deal with all three possibilities for the most significant bits:-

$\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\\end{vmatrix}$

$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&1\\\end{vmatrix}$

$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0\\\end{vmatrix}$

Comment: Can you elaborate on your method? I am not sure I am following. The first two steps are straightforward, but then I am not sure. Why are you subtracting 1? I know there is a duplicate in there, but do you have a general method of finding it? Then you are ignoring the first two bits. But they can't be 00. So how are you counting the duplicates?

Comment: How general and practical is this method? Could you for example apply it if I gave you the interval [2378901, 12329006] without a computer?

Comment: @Thanassis. Re the duplicate. For the range being considered the possibilities are just 101**,*101*,**101, with 10101 the only duplicate.

Comment: @Thanassis. Re only using the last 6 bits, All the numbers are 011***** and therefore we only need consider 1*****.

Comment: @Thanassis. Re. general and practical. Roughly speaking you would need 3 more steps whenever the gap doubles so unless you spotted some short cuts it would require perhaps 10 times the number of steps used for the post.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with the numbers mentioned in the comments: $n_{10}=100$ and $k_{10}=199$. Thus, we need to search between the binary numbers between $11 00100$ and $110 00111$. So $y_2$ has either 7 or 8 digits. Let the numbers in the binary form be $b_1b_2b_3b_4b_5b_6b_7b_8$. 
\begin{equation}
011 00100\leq b_1b_2b_3b_4b_5b_6b_7b_8\leq 110 00111.
\end{equation}

Let's look at numbers with $101$ at different positions:

- **Case 1: $b_1b_2b_3=101$:** All numbers such that $b_1b_2b_3=101$ belong to $S$; there are $2^5$ numbers in $S$ of this form.
- **Case 2: $b_2b_3b_4=101$:** There are no such numbers in $S$.
- **Case 3: $b_3b_4b_5=101$:** For such numbers, $b_1b_2=01,10$, and the numbers with $b_1b_2=10$ are already counted as case 1. Therefore, $b_1b_2=01$; there are $2^3$ numbers in $S$ of this form.
- **Case 4: $b_4b_5b_6=101$:** For such numbers, $011\leq b_1b_2b_3\leq 101$, and the numbers with $b_1b_2b_3= 101$ and $b_2b_3=10$ are already counted. Therefore, $b_1b_2b_3=011,100$; there are $2^3$ numbers in $S$ of this form.
- **Case 5: $b_5b_6b_7=101$:** For such numbers, $0110\leq b_1b_2b_3b_4\leq 1011$, and the numbers with $b_1b_2b_3= 101$, $b_2b_3b_4=101$ and $b_3b_4=10$ are already counted. Thus, $0111\leq b_1b_2b_3b_4\leq 1001$, and therefore, $b_1b_2b_3b_4=0111,1000,1001$; there are $6$ numbers in $S$ of this form.
- **Case 6: $b_6b_7b_8=101$:** For such numbers, $01100\leq b_1b_2b_3b_4\leq 11000$, and the numbers with $b_1b_2b_3= 101$, $b_2b_3b_4=101$, $b_3b_4b_5=101$ and $b_4b_5=10$ are already counted. Thus, $b_1b_2b_3b_4b_5=01111,10000,10001,10011,11000,11001$; there are $6$ numbers in $S$ of this form.

The total number = $32+8+8+6+6=60$